# Google api autocomplete doesn't recognize address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

`Courchevel, Saint-Bon-Tarentaise, France` appears in the results but when I want to use this address `geocode` doesn't recognize it.

It recognizes only this one `Courchevel 1650, Saint-Bon-Tarentaise, France`.

How do I make the original address recongizable?

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete, destination;
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
        (document.getElementById('from')), {
            types: ['geocode']
        }
    );

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

    destination = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
        (document.getElementById('to')), {
            types: ['geocode']
        }
    );

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    destination.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddressDestination);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}
// [END region_fillform]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to reproduce the issue, testing those two addresses on the Google [Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) and the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete). It seems like Google is trying to place your search somewhere and is just putting it in the general "Courchevel region."

It seems there is not a proper way to fix this using the Google API, except for using more precise addresses or by [reporting the address issue](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088) to Google and waiting for them to fix the API. (I think they actually respond quickly to these.)

I tried to verify the address using [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/demo). It matched your address to this, and I'm not sure if it's correct:

[image]

I would suggest using an address API, like SmartyStreets, that does verification (meaning, it checks against address data to find a known address and pinpoint it rather than just trying to pinpoint all search terms as they are entered; it's especially handy if the address is more important to you than the map or if you're doing shipping or something like that).

Full disclosure: I worked for SmartyStreets.